# Hyperledger fabric where the blockchain state are saved

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I using the hyperledger fabric network with 2 organisation. Now my question, where does the fabric store the blockchain state. Because i am facing the issue, when i turn down the organisation using the docker, All state of blockchain are vanished/delete. How i can keep the track of or save blockchain state, so i don't want to start the blockchain all the time from state zero. Please suggest me.
even for the fabric blockchain explorer also.

Comment: it uses file system to store blockchain state so you need to make sure while you stop docker containers you don't delete the volumes created by container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use persistent volumes to ensure that the data is not stored on the container filesystem else it will be destroyed when the container(s) are destroyed.

For **peers**, the two key attributes in `core.yaml` are:

`peer.fileSystemPath` - this defaults to `/var/hyperledger/production` and is where the ledger, installed chaincodes, etc are kept. The corresponding environment variable is `CORE_PEER_FILESYSTEMPATH`.

`peer.mspConfigPath` - where the local MSP info is stored. The corresponding environment variable is `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH`.

For **orderers**, the two key attributes in `orderer.yaml` are:

`FileLedger.Location` - this defaults to `/var/hyperledger/production/orderer` and is where the channel ledgers are stored.  The corresponding environment variable is `ORDERER_FILELEDGER_LOCATION`.

`General.LocalMSPDir` - where the local MSP info is stored. The corresponding environment variable is `ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR`.

Answer (score 0):

Easily, you can map the content of the docker outside the docker and save it.

In example, for orderer, all its content is inside /var/hyperledger/production/orderer.
You can map this folder outside in a local folder.
In this way you will see the content of the docker folder even without logging the docker bash.

Now you can copy this content in another folder, let's say backup.
When you re-create the docker, you can map the backup folder so that it will start with the previous content you had inside.